# Type of Class in C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli

I am working on C++/CLI Wrapper for C Static Library.Static Library has 10 function in it.

THis C++/CLI Wrapper will Expose 10 API to C# Application.The Wrapper Will be in the Form of dll.

The Wrapper Will be Used in C# Application.

Now I am trying to add a class in C++/CLi application which will expose function to C# application I am getting Many Option like

1. C++ Class
2. CLR Class
   a. Component Class
   b.Installer Class
   c. Windows Form
   d. Installer Class

I am bit confused which I need to select out of it as I am new bee in C++/CLI

Comment: Are you talking about the new class wizard ? Ditch this, you only need three lines to declare the class. Read about C++/CLI there: http://www.functionx.com/cppcli/index.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a

> CLR Class - Component

since it can be consumed by .NET clients.
CLR class is declared as follows

```
ref class Wrapper {....}
```

However in your scenario you could also write a dynamic library and pinvoke the methods from .NET client.

Comment: Inside CLR class there are many options mentioned above.which one to select.I am using VS 2010

Comment: I am asking when you add class from wizard. which option to select from various option mentioned above.

Comment: Yeah Wrapper Will Be Dll. Please Confirm PInovke will done at .Net Client Right.

Comment: If you write a Ref class you don't need pInvoke. You can directly add reference to the dll. pinvoke method was non c++cli solution.

Comment: I guess in My case PInvoke won't work as it a static C Library.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if your question has been entirely answered, but a Component class creates a class that implements an IComponent interface for remoting/ inter process communication purposes. Didn't seem like what you were looking for.

I think what you were looking for i just a "template" to create a managed class?
In that case all you need to do is select C++ in the wizard and make sure the "Managed" check box on the right hand side is selected.